# How to get aggregated record from the collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to find the customer with highest bank balance from bank_json collection in mongodb.

This is the structure I have.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575cdc27b2fdf5552d4985ad"),
    "first_name" : "JAMES",
    "last_name" : "SMITH",
    "accounts" : [
        {
            "account_type" : "Savings",
            "account_balance" : 8995952.153640702,
            "currency" : "PESO"
        },
        {
            "account_type" : "Checking",
            "account_balance" : 3901436.5580737568,
            "currency" : "USD"
        }
    ]
}
```

and there are at least 50000 records of customers.

I am trying to find the customer with highest bank balance.

This is what I did but it is not getting my desired result.

```
 db.bank_data.aggregate([ { $unwind: "$accounts" },
{ $group: { _id: "$id", sum: { $max: "$accounts.account_balance" }}}])
    { "_id" : null, "sum" : 9999989.46325779 }
```

so I am getting highest balance which is fine. but I also want first_name and last_name of this record which has highest balance.

How can I get this one ?

Answer (score 0):

you try sort balance and get first row.

```
db.collection.find().sort({account_balance:-1}).limit(1).pretty()
```

Comment: Nope. This does not check for highest balance at all.

Comment: Binh probably was thinking to do sort on "accounts.account_balance"? not _id:-1 sort?

Comment: sorry, this is my code example, you can sort balance field